# Unity lanucher bug - problem with stacked aps

Tags: unity, 15.04, launcher

I have problem with launcher, i'm not able to switch between running aps if they are piled - lets say i have 2x terminal running, when i click on terminal icon in launcher instead this window manager everything disappear and reappear after few seconds. I'm able to successful change with tab or right click

Kindly ask for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem , here is solution for all people who struggle with unity bugs.

```
sudo su
apt-get update
apt-get autoclean
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-dekstop
apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

If you still have problem you can try reinstall video drivers.
If there will be still problem - well i think only reinstall left.